# How to create a document that looks like a blank word document?

Tags: msword

I wish to create document that simply looks like the blank word document

[image]

How can I do so? The default latex code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Blank Document

\end{document}
```

does have have the same spacing

[image]

Comment: What is exactly your problem? Do you want to get rid of the paragraph indentation? Do you want to have thinner margins? What is the point in having a *blank* page as a document?

Comment: @SebGlav sorry, I would like thinner margins, exactly like in microsoft word's

Comment: Even in MSWord, you could have thick margins, but anyway... take a look at the `geometry` package.

Comment: Have a look at https://ctan.javinator9889.com/macros/latex/contrib/wordlike/wordlike.pdf . I’ve never used it — if I need a Word-like document, I just use Word.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this after your comment using `geometry` package?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=4cm,right=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum**: If you can decrease the space between the two lines there is also the `setspace` package + `\setstretch{.2}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{.2}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly does `changepage` do in your answer? You're not using it in any way, to get the same output you can just drop it and only use `geometry`.

Comment: @Skillmon Hi. It decrease the space between the rows. I have read thus.

Comment: No, it really does nothing here, and afaik `changepage` does not mangle the `\baselineskip`. Just compile the document once with and once without `changepage`, there'll be no difference. If you don't believe me, box the paragraph up and compare the `\showbox` of both runs, with and without `changepage`.

Comment: I believe you surely. My English language it is very low. I have understood other things about this package. Do I delete the question or can you edit it appropriately?

Comment: Just remove the `changepage` stuff from your answer. You're showing the use of `geometry` correctly (which is what could be used to reproduce Word-like margins).

Comment: @Skillmon Thank you very much.........:-)